# Find the length of an integer within a string

Tags: c, file, parsing, pointers, if-statement

If I've got a text file like:

```
8f5
```

I can easily use `strstr`to parse the values `8` and `5` out of it.
As such:

```
//while fgets.. etc (other variables and declarations before it)
char * ptr = strstr(str,"f");
if(ptr != NULL)
{
    int a = atol(ptr-1); // value of 8
    int b = atol(ptr+1); // value of 5
}
```

But what if the values where two decimals long? I could `add +2 and -2` to each atol call. But I can't predict when the values are less than 10 or greater, for instance

```
12f6
```

or `15f15` As the values are random each time (i.e either one decimal or two). Is there a way to check the length of the values between the string, and then use `atol()`?

Comment: Well, you could always write some code, eg. a char-by-char state machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `atol(str)` and `atol(ptr+1)`, if I am reading the question correctly. This will get you the two numbers separated by the f, regardless of how long they are.

Set `*ptr = '\0'` first if you don't wish to rely on the fact that garbage characters stop atol from parsing.

Comment: so setting a equal to atol(str) and b to atol(ptr+1) ?

Comment: I would recommend you consider `sscanf("%df%d", &a, &b)` however, if you do not have a specific need for doing things the way you are.

Comment: @Segmented `scanf()` would not work, it's not for regular expression matching.

Comment: @iharob The question does not require regular expression matching, sscanf does sufficiently pattern match, and in this case it *would* work, which you are welcome to verify.

Comment: @Segmented `scanf()` specifiers stop scanning when they find a white space, I don't think that the format string you give above would work, perhaps `"%d%*1c%d"` could work. And in my opinion `ato*` functions are useless because you cant do error checking so I never use them.

Comment: @iharob The format I provided would parse correctly what the OP wishes to parse - write a test program to verify if you must, but it is besides the point. He did not ask for a code review, he asked how to do something specific with `atol` which is what I provided in my answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

If the text is always similar to the one you posted, then you can get the three parts of the string with the following code, and you can parse another token if there is a white space between them

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char  string[] = "12f5 1234x2912";
    char *next;

    next = string;
    while (*next != '\0') /* While not at the end of the string */
    {
        char   separator[100];
        size_t counter;
        int    firstNumber;
        int    secondNumber;

        /* Get the first number */
        firstNumber = strtol(next, &next, 10);
        counter     = 0;
        /* Skip all non-numeric characters and store them in `separator' */
        while ((*next != '\0') && (isdigit(*next) == 0))
            separator[counter++] = *next++;
        /* nul terminate `separator' */
        separator[counter] = '\0';
        /* extract the second number */
        secondNumber = strtol(next, &next, 10);
        /* show me how you did it */
        printf("%d:%s:%d\n", firstNumber, separator, secondNumber);
        /* skip any number of white space characters */
        while ((*next != '\0') && (isspace(*next) != 0))
            next++;
    }
}
```

in the example above you can see that there are to strings being parsed, you can read the [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) manual page to understand why this algorithm works.

Normally you should not use `atoi()` or `atol()` functions because you cant validate the input string, since there is no way to know whether the function succeded or not.

Comment: One minor problem: `strtol(next, &next, base)` is something to avoid sometimes.  What if there was no number to parse, such as "f5" instead of "8f5"?  `ptr` would still be at the start of the string, `errno` would not be set, and the returned value would be `0`, which would indicate "0f5".  I could understand if this was desired behavior, but it likely isn't due to its inconsistency with the rest of the "grammar".  In particular, it would mean "f" would result in `a=0, b=0` without setting `errno`, but what if there was "fg" instead of "8f5g3"?  "fg" likely should trigger an error.